# How to grouping list by a field and select into groups min of another field via linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of flights that I try to grouping that with date field and then select into it minimum price into per group. At the result I should get 
cheapest flights per days.

[image]

```
(from flights in aFlightList
                                   where flights.IsDeparture && flights.OnlyTour == "0" && flights.OnlyPhone == "0"
                                   group flights by flights.FlightDateFull
                                       into grouping
                                       select grouping.OrderBy(a => a.FlightDateFull).First()).ToArray();
```

This code grouping list by date but can not get cheapest flights.
I try such as  this :

```
(from flights in aFlightList
                                   where flights.IsDeparture && flights.OnlyTour == "0" && flights.OnlyPhone == "0"
                                   group flights by flights.FlightDateFull
                                       into grouping
                                       select grouping.OrderBy(a => a.FlightDateFull).Min(d=>d.PriceView)).ToArray();
```

This way get error.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a `group by` operation is a list of groupings, where the grouping consists of a key and list of elements sharing that key.

Let take your first query. The group by operation groups the `aFlightList` by date, so there is no need further ordering the group elements by date (it's one and the same). But you can order them by price, so `First` will return the element with minimum price. Finally, since the order of the `group by` resulting groups might not be what you want, you can order the **groupings** by the key (or part of it).

With all that being said, the modified query could be like this:

```
(from flights in aFlightList
 where flights.IsDeparture && flights.OnlyTour == "0" && flights.OnlyPhone == "0"
 group flights by flights.FlightDateFull
 into grouping
 orderby grouping.Key
 select grouping.OrderBy(e => e.PriceView).First())
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object with the results you want and perform the selection on that. Example:

```
    class Flight
    {
        public bool IsDeparture;
        public string OnlyTour;
        public string OnlyPhone;
        public DateTime FlightDateFull;
        public decimal PriceView;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FlightTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var flightList = new List<Flight> {
            new  Flight { IsDeparture = true, OnlyPhone = "0", OnlyTour = "0", FlightDateFull = new DateTime(2016,8,7), PriceView = 1 },
            new  Flight { IsDeparture = true, OnlyPhone = "0", OnlyTour = "0", FlightDateFull = new DateTime(2016,8,7), PriceView = 2 },
            new  Flight { IsDeparture = true, OnlyPhone = "0", OnlyTour = "0", FlightDateFull = new DateTime(2016,8,8), PriceView = 2 },
            new  Flight { IsDeparture = true, OnlyPhone = "0", OnlyTour = "0", FlightDateFull = new DateTime(2016,8,8), PriceView = 3 }
        };

        // Act
        var result = (from flights in flightList
                      where flights.IsDeparture && flights.OnlyTour == "0" && flights.OnlyPhone == "0"
                      group flights by flights.FlightDateFull into grouping
                      select new { Date = grouping.Key, MinPrice = grouping.Min(a => a.PriceView) }).OrderBy(a => a.Date).ToList();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 8, 7), result[0].Date);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result[0].MinPrice);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 8, 8), result[1].Date);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result[1].MinPrice);
    }
```